# Hibernate não cria tabela automaticamente no mysql

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

Estou estudando Spring com um pouco de Hibernate, onde parei numa situação que não consigo passar.

Eu configurei o código com o hibernate para a criação de tabelas no banco porém quando rodo a aplicação ela não cria.

Minha classe modelo:

```
@Entity

@Table(name="cliente")

public class Cliente {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;

    private String nome;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }
}
```

Minha properties:

```
server.port=${port:8080}
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clientesdb
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
```

MySQL sem senha.

Estou fazendo algo de errado?

Comment: geralmente eu coloco `create=true;` na url, veja se funciona desta maneira: `spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clientesdb;create=true` além disto vc precisa definir o dialeto `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolvi colocando a anotação para escanear o pacote da minha entidade na minha classe Application:

@EntityScan(basePackages = {"br.com.springboot.model"})

Answer (score 1):

Falta adicionar o `dialect` em suas properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/clientesdb​;create=true
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Coloquei também o `show-sql` caso não de certo, poste a sql que está sendo gerada

Outro ponto importante também é verificar o import de sua entity, verifique se o seu import é `javax.persistence.Entity`

Comment: Ola, eu resolvi o problema colocando na minha classe Application a anotação: @EntityScan(basePackages = {"br.com.springboot.model"}) Como se tivesse forçando a achar o pacote da entidade. Esse import que você mencionou "javax.persistence.Entity" ele serve pra que?

Comment: @PhilippeNunes O que ele quis dizer sobre o `javax.persistence.Entity` foi isso: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/168101/132

Comment: @Philippe Nunes Geralmente o próprio spring faz o mapeamento do `basePackages` quando você utiliza `@SprintBootApplication` ou `@ComponentScan`, provavelmente é algum tipo de configuração que não deixou ele mapear, nas ultimas versões do jpa vc é obrigado a setar a entidade dentro do `EntityScan` do XML, porém com spring isto não é necessário.
Obrigado @Victor Stafusa, é isto mesmo, acredito que ele possa ter importado o `@Entity` de outro pacote, desta forma o spring não conseguiria mapear

Answer (score 1):

Eu estava com esse mesmo erro.

Consegui resolver usando:`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update`. Vale lembrar que eu tinha colocado `?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC` no meu datasource.url, mas acho que isso serviu apenas para outro problema que tive antes.
Meu properties ficou desta forma:

`spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nome_do_database?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC spring.datasource.username=usuario spring.datasource.password=senha spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi meu problema fazendo o import correto(javax.persistence.Entity)
Estou usando spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.